# Pass dynamic variable value from robot framework to python file

Tags: python, robotframework

I'm trying to pass a dynamic value from robot framework to a variable in python file (which have all my variables).

In .py file I have the following:

```
index = BuiltIn().get_variable_value("${iIndex}")
MyDynamicVar="xpath://div["+str(index)+"]"  #or without str
```

and in .robot file I have:

```
    FOR  ${i}  IN RANGE  ${c}
            ${iIndex} =    Set Variable    ${i+1}
            log to console   ${MyDynamicVar}
            log to console    ***************************************
    END
```

I tried to set an initial value in variables sections in robot file, and the value changed, but I need the value to be dynamic!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`str.format`](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/#2-new-style-string-formatting-strformat) will do the trick for you, which would give the following in the variable file:

```python
MyDynamicVar="xpath://div[{}]"
```

Then you can use the [Extended variable syntax](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#extended-variable-syntax) to call the `format` function on the string like:

```
*** Settings ***
Variables    variables.py

*** Test Cases ***
Test
    FOR  ${i}  IN RANGE  5
            ${iIndex} =    Set Variable    ${i+1}
            log to console   ${MyDynamicVar.format(${iIndex})}
            log to console    ***************************************
    END
```

You can even simplify to `${MyDynamicVar.format(${i+1})}`. Here are the results:

```
==============================================================================
Test
==============================================================================
Test                                                                  xpath://div[1]
***************************************
xpath://div[2]
***************************************
xpath://div[3]
***************************************
xpath://div[4]
***************************************
xpath://div[5]
***************************************
Test                                                                  | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: @A.Han I forgot to mention that a variable file is executed once when imported so any latter change will not take effect. That is why your approach did not update the variable. :)